# More test cc bank accounts for intuit customer account data API.

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

[Test account](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/testing_calls_to_the_api) provided by intuit are limited. I am looking for more api Data in general and for getInvestmentPositions specifically. it here away to generate test accounts ? or is there any other than . [these accounts](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/testing_calls_to_the_api) ?

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately there is no other dummy FIs available for testing.

Answer (score 0):

At `EARN.org`,  I had a UC  Berkeley student intern build an  mock  object system for the Intuit Customer Data Banking API. It's built with Python, Pyramid, SQLAlchemy  and the Cornice frameworks.

We are using it to test our micro-saving applications. It was designed to provide more test accounts and let us simulate the effect of transactions in the past or future.  It **NOT** fully featured, we didn't implement the security features of the real Intuit API. We did just enough work to create, banks and user accounts with transactions.

It's on github at [https://github.com/earnsf/BankingTestAPI](https://github.com/earnsf/BankingTestAPI/tree/master/EARN_TESTAPI)

We are using with the [aggcat](https://github.com/glenbot/python-aggcat) Python wrapper. I'd say its still very nascent piece of code. We welcome  other collaborators who can help move this project forward.